# An array of dictionaries; comparing each {key, value} pair; and combining dictionaries

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to optimize a nested for loops that **compares an element in the array with the rest of the element in the array**.

There's two part, the first part is for example,  an Array has 3 elements, and each element is a dictionary:

```
[{"someKey_1":"a"}, {"someKey_1":"b"}, {"somekey_1":"a"}]
```

---

1st iteration(1st element compares with 2nd element):

Test key of "someKey" for two elements, since `a != b`, then we do nothing

---

2st iteration(1st element compares with 3nd element):

Test key of "someKey" for two elements, since `a == a`, we do some logic

---

The code(Sudo):

```
for idx, first_dictionary in enumerate(set_of_pk_values):
    for second_dictionary in (set_of_pk_values[idx+1:]):
        if (first_dictionary['someKey'] == second_dictionary['someKey']):
                #Some Logic
```

The #Some Logic part of the code requires combining keys from one dictionary to another, for example:

```
for key in val_2.keys():
    val[key]=val_2[key]
```

The Code:

```
newList = []
skipList = []
checked = []
getter = itemgetter("predecessor")
getter_2 = itemgetter("setid_hash")

for idx, val in enumerate(set_of_pk_values):
    if(idx not in skipList):
        for val_2 in set_of_pk_values[idx+1:]:
            if(idx not in checked):
                try:
                    if (ast.literal_eval(getter(val)) == ast.literal_eval(getter(val_2))):
                        for key in val_2.keys():
                            if(key != "block" and key != "username" and key != "setid" 
                                and key != "setid_hash" and key != "predecessor"
                                and key != "time_string" and key != "condition"):
                                    val[key]=val_2[key]
                        skipList.append(idx)
                except:
                    if (getter(val) == getter(val_2)):
                        for key in val_2.keys():
                            if(key != "block" and key != "username" and key != "setid" 
                                and key != "setid_hash" and key != "predecessor"
                                and key != "time_string" and key != "condition"):
                                    val[key]=val_2[key]
                        skipList.append(idx)
    checked.append(idx)
```

Sample input (set_of_pk_values):

```
{'username': u'radcad', 'predecessor': u"[u'6a5e4bc9a328c1aeb52c565b675e6141', u'818428a59215e75d76111c8ca29a314d', u'6c
acfc059508f8cb716ad0126f001f84']", 'time_string': u'2014/06/26@07:02:40', 'S.clpe_leafcell.UTC_Post_start': u'1403766190', 'setid_hash': u'14443f7238927d6e95
befbe12ecc6dd0', 'setid': u'1986068', 'block': u'simple_buff'}
{'username': u'radcad', 'predecessor': u"[u'8d899b7eec936785dfcbcf86879bd2b7', u'e0cd1b80ee537d2e9ce5efaf3542da22']", 't
ime_string': u'2014/06/27@07:02:15', 'S.clpe_leafcell.UTC_Post_start': u'1403852565', 'setid_hash': u'9172da57b62419041e
c76524de72e235', 'setid': u'1991185', 'block': u'simple_buff'}
{'username': u'radcad', 'predecessor': u"[u'755b2dafcace3c56a9f409899e219708', u'dd7e980b20027b8120c7884459bfab44']", 't
ime_string': u'2014/06/28@07:02:40', 'S.clpe_leafcell.UTC_Post_start': u'1403938989', 'setid_hash': u'0d7f3d2771a8defae0
f0c969cbdd8938', 'setid': u'1994886', 'block': u'simple_buff'}
{'username': u'radcad', 'predecessor': u"[u'8ccdc497036cc700512e44e53ae3b504', u'3ba9c3963d37d0415489ad73a66400d1', u'12
896a98310e9be61b60f8575bdc86fa']", 'S.rcxt_maxcl.Predecessors': u'clpe_leafcell', 'time_string': u'2015/03/07@03:05:48',
 'setid_hash': u'ed47755f1067c891322a9a778c4d8bc8', 'setid': u'3094622', 'block': u'simple_buff'}
{'username': u'radcad', 'predecessor': u"[u'6a5e4bc9a328c1aeb52c565b675e6141', u'818428a59215e75d76111c8ca29a314d', u'6c
acfc059508f8cb716ad0126f001f84']", 'S.rcxt_maxcl.Predecessors': u'clpe_leafcell', 'time_string': u'2015/03/08@03:06:26',
 'setid_hash': u'ffce9f0c46f3459acbba4f0ced884f3a', 'setid': u'3095862', 'block': u'simple_buff'}
```

So Based on the sample input, what we want to do is compare if predecessors are the same, if they are the same, let's take these two as for example:

```
{'username': u'radcad', 'predecessor': u"[u'6a5e4bc9a328c1aeb52c565b675e6141', u'818428a59215e75d76111c8ca29a314d', u'6c
    acfc059508f8cb716ad0126f001f84']", 'time_string': u'2014/06/26@07:02:40', 'S.clpe_leafcell.UTC_Post_start': u'1403766190', 'setid_hash': u'14443f7238927d6e95
    befbe12ecc6dd0', 'setid': u'1986068', 'block': u'simple_buff'}
{'username': u'radcad', 'predecessor': u"[u'6a5e4bc9a328c1aeb52c565b675e6141', u'818428a59215e75d76111c8ca29a314d', u'6c
    acfc059508f8cb716ad0126f001f84']", 'S.rcxt_maxcl.Predecessors': u'clpe_leafcell', 'time_string': u'2015/03/08@03:06:26',
     'setid_hash': u'ffce9f0c46f3459acbba4f0ced884f3a', 'setid': u'3095862', 'block': u'simple_buff'}
```

Since they have the same predecessors, we will combine these two dictionaries except the key's: username, time_string, setid_hash, setid, condition (if exists),

```
 {'username': u'radcad', 'predecessor': u"[u'6a5e4bc9a328c1aeb52c565b675e6141', u'818428a59215e75d76111c8ca29a314d', u'6c
        acfc059508f8cb716ad0126f001f84']", 'time_string': u'2014/06/26@07:02:40', 'S.clpe_leafcell.UTC_Post_start': u'1403766190', 'S.rcxt_maxcl.Predecessors': u'clpe_leafcell', 'setid_hash': u'14443f7238927d6e95
        befbe12ecc6dd0', 'setid': u'1986068', 'block': u'simple_buff'}
```

---

The second part is very similar to the previous example (3 items in the list), in the same dictionary, we have an array associated with a key(now there's a single dictionary with two keys in each element of the array), let's say:

```
[{"someKey_1":[b,f]}{"someKey_2":a}, 
 {"someKey_1":[e,f]}{"someKey_2":b}, 
 {"somekey_1":[h,k]}{"someKey_2":c}]
```

---

1st iteration (1st element compares with 2nd element):

loops through the array with the key: someKey_1

`b == b` (2nd element's someKey_2), then do some logic

`f != b` (2nd element's someKey_2), no logic is done

---

2nd iteration (1st element compares with 3rd element):

loops through the array with the key: someKey_1

`b == c` (3rd element's someKey_2), then do some logic

`f != c` (3rd element's someKey_2), no logic is done

---

The code (Sudo):

```
for idx, val in enumerate(set_of_pk_values):
    for idx_2, val_2 in enumerate(set_of_pk_values):
        for pred in val['someKey_1']:
            if(val_2['someKey_2'] == pred):
                #Some Logic
```

The #Some Logic part of the code is the same as the first nested loop, which requires combining keys and their values from one dictionary to another, for example:

```
for key in val_2.keys():
    val[key]=val_2[key]
```

The Code:

```
newList = []
skipList = []
checked = []
getter = itemgetter("predecessor")
getter_2 = itemgetter("setid_hash")

for idx, val in enumerate(set_of_pk_values):
    if(idx not in skipList):
        for idx_2, val_2 in enumerate(set_of_pk_values):
            if(idx != idx_2):
                try:
                    for pred in ast.literal_eval(getter(val)):
                        if(getter_2(val_2) == pred):
                            for key in val_2.keys():
                                if(key != "block" and key != "username" and key != "setid" 
                                    and key != "setid_hash" and key != "predecessor"
                                    and key != "time_string" and key != "condition"):
                                        val[key]=val_2[key]
                            skipList.append(idx_2)
                except:
                    for pred in getter(val):
                        if(getter_2(val_2) == pred):
                            for key in val_2.keys():
                                if(key != "block" and key != "username" and key != "setid" 
                                    and key != "setid_hash" and key != "predecessor"
                                    and key != "time_string" and key != "condition"):
                                        val[key]=val_2[key]
                            skipList.append(idx_2)
```

Similarly what this is supposed to do is the compare the array of predecessor with setid_hash, if they are equal, then we combine.

---

Full Code:

```
def test():
    set_of_pk_values = []
    cache = chartCache.objects.get(username_chartNum="Test 3_leimax", openedConfig="chartTable_774164170")
    data = chartCache_Data.objects.filter(ID = cache)
    max_value = data.aggregate(Max('counter'))['counter__max']
    if(max_value != None):
        if(max_value != 0):
            cached = True
        for i in xrange(0, max_value+1):
            newItem = {}
            set_of_pk_values.append(newItem)
        for items in data.iterator():
            set_of_pk_values[items.counter][str(items.key)] = items.value
    newList = []
    skipList = []
    checked = []
    getter = itemgetter("predecessor")
    getter_2 = itemgetter("setid_hash")
    print str(len(set_of_pk_values))
    timeNow = datetime.datetime.now()


    ##############################################
    #First Nested For Loop
    ##############################################
    for idx, val in enumerate(set_of_pk_values):
        if(idx not in skipList):
            for val_2 in set_of_pk_values[idx+1:]:
                if(idx not in checked):
                    try:
                        if (ast.literal_eval(getter(val)) == ast.literal_eval(getter(val_2))):
                            for key in val_2.keys():
                                if(key != "block" and key != "username" and key != "setid" 
                                    and key != "setid_hash" and key != "predecessor"
                                    and key != "time_string" and key != "condition"):
                                        val[key]=val_2[key]
                            skipList.append(idx)
                    except:
                        if (getter(val) == getter(val_2)):
                            for key in val_2.keys():
                                if(key != "block" and key != "username" and key != "setid" 
                                    and key != "setid_hash" and key != "predecessor"
                                    and key != "time_string" and key != "condition"):
                                        val[key]=val_2[key]
                            skipList.append(idx)
        checked.append(idx)

    ##############################################
    #Second Nested For Loop
    ##############################################
    for idx, val in enumerate(set_of_pk_values):
        if(idx not in skipList):
            for idx_2, val_2 in enumerate(set_of_pk_values):
                if(idx != idx_2):
                    try:
                        for pred in ast.literal_eval(getter(val)):
                            if(getter_2(val_2) == pred):
                                for key in val_2.keys():
                                    if(key != "block" and key != "username" and key != "setid" 
                                        and key != "setid_hash" and key != "predecessor"
                                        and key != "time_string" and key != "condition"):
                                            val[key]=val_2[key]
                                skipList.append(idx_2)
                    except:
                        for pred in getter(val):
                            if(getter_2(val_2) == pred):
                                for key in val_2.keys():
                                    if(key != "block" and key != "username" and key != "setid" 
                                        and key != "setid_hash" and key != "predecessor"
                                        and key != "time_string" and key != "condition"):
                                            val[key]=val_2[key]
                                skipList.append(idx_2)


    for idx, val in enumerate(set_of_pk_values):
        if(idx not in skipList):
            newList.append(val)
    set_of_pk_values = newList
    print str(len(set_of_pk_values))
    timeEnd = datetime.datetime.now()
    print str(timeEnd - timeNow)
```

---

Currently the runtime for the first nested loop: 21 seconds, and the second nested loop is around 19 seconds. Compared to other processes, ranging from 0-1 seconds, this part is clearly a bottleneck.

Can anybody point me to the right direction on how to optimize this piece of simple, yet extremely time consuming code?

---

Edit:

Try to do an ast.literal_eval before nested loops:

```
for items in set_of_pk_values:
    for key in item.keys():
        getter = itemgetter(key)
        try:
            toChange = ast.literal_eval(getter(items))
            items[key] = toChange
        except:
            pass
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### `ast.literal_eval(...)`

If we can remove your calls to `ast.literal_eval(...)` we should see a nice reduction in the run time of your loops. But, why can we remove this you ask? Consider:

```
    m = '[0, 1, 2, ... , 9,999]' # a str representation of list w/ 10k elements, 0-9999
    n = '[0, 1, 2]'

    x = ast.literal.eval(m)
    y = ast.literal.eval(n)

    x == range(10000) # true
```

As you can see from the snippet above, `ast.literal_eval(...)` will parse and evaluate whatever string you pass it, and return a literal representation of that string (assuming of course that the string represents a valid literal). Clearly, it is more efficient to compare `m` and `n` than it is to compare `x` and `y`. Also, it doesn't appear that you are concerned with whether or not `val` or `val_2` is a valid python literal because under the scenario that `ast.literal_eval(...)`throws an exception, you default to just comparing the strings returned by `getter(val)` and `getter(val_2)`. Long story short you can remove the `try: / except:` and just use the statements you have under the `except` clause.

### `for key in val_2.keys()`

The above loop occurs as the inner-most loop of both loops `1` and `2`. With each iteration you check that `key` isn't equivalent to 7 other possible key values. 6 of these key values occur in the data you've presented and the 7th (`condition`) doesn't. It should be more efficient to replace:

```
for key in val_2.keys():
   if(key != "block" and key != "username" and key != "setid" 
      and key != "setid_hash" and key != "predecessor" 
      and key != "time_string" and key != "condition"):
           val[key]=val_2[key]
```

with:

```
# put this at the top of the test function 
x_keys = set(['block', 'username', 'setid', 'setid_hash', 'predecessor', 'time_string', 'condition'])
# ...
for key in set(val_2.keys()) - x_keys:
    val[key] = val_2[key]
```

Comment: I have some literal representation of strings that was inside the key value pair of the dictionary. Thinking about that, I was able to write a for loop that tries to change the key,value pair first. Then I don't need to test for ast.literal_eval later. This had significant speedup, from 20 seconds to milliseconds.